# Why would a Firebase background function on Node.js 8 complain about an event parameter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After a recent update, firebase-tools wants me to set my package.json engines setting to either node 6 or 8. When you set it to 6 it deploys the functions on Node 6 and otherwise Node 8.

With firebase-functions 1.0 the background function signature changed from `event` to `data, context`. I have migrated all my background functions long ago.

I noticed that according to the @gloud/functions docs (which differs from firebase-functions) you explicitly set the Node deployment target, and the distinction in API between the Node 6 and 8 runtimes is this same event vs data/context signature.

So in @gloud/functions the API change got rolled out in a different way than with firebase-functions.

Wat seems weird is that if I now deploy my firebase-functions with engines set to node 8, I get errors like this:

> Cloud function needs to be called with an event parameter.

When I set engines to node 6, it says it is deploying my code on Node.js 6, and everything works as before.

Now that seems to be the opposite of what I would expect!

So I am using the up-to-date background functions API but I can't seem to run them properly on Node.js 8. Something seems to be messed up somewhere. Any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the version of `firebase-functions` [needs to be 2.0.0+](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v4.0.0) for node 8 runtime.

This error message appears in 1.x.x `firebase-functions` for me, and is gone after I upgrade it.

Note that `firebase-admin` [also needs to be 5.13.0+](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/295#issuecomment-409320154).

Comment: I'm not sure which of these applied to my case, but it sounds likely that this would have been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're mixing up a bunch of things.

First, @google-cloud/functions and firebase-functions may not be in sync.  They work completely diffrently.  Don't assume that the conventions for one will apply to the other.  When writing functions for Firebase, only use firebase-functions and the Firebase CLI.  You won't be able to use gcloud.

Second, the Firebase APIs changed in firebase-functions 1.0.0.  It sounds like you're aware of this.  The API changes have nothing to do with the targeted node version.  Node version should have no effect on the APIs.

Comment: I am not using @google-cloud/functions. I only referred to it because this issue seems to occur between node 6 and 8 deployments. I know for Firebase it should not make a difference, but that's why I think it is so strange. I can not find any reason why deploying the functions on Node 8 would make the API incompatible. I will try again to deploy to Node 8 with firebase-tools 4.0.2. Maybe something was fixed since...

Comment: If you have a problem, please be sure to note exactly the versions of everything you're using (from package.json, etc.).

Comment: I have upgraded firebase-tools to 4.0.2 and deployed my code again on Node.js 8. Now the error doesn't seem to appear anymore.